# BreezeSharp - Enum serialization fails

Tags: .net, breeze, breeze-sharp

This question is sequel of [BreezeSharp - ExecuteQuery fails with NullReferenceExeption](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23681315/breezesharp-executequery-fails-with-nullreferenceexeption)

In my server side entity I have enum property:

```
[Required]
public DataStore DataStore { get; set; }
```

This property in client side entity is defined like this:

```
    public DataStore DataStore
    {
        get { return GetValue<DataStore>(); }
        set { SetValue(value); 
    }
```

When controller method return data to client, serialization error occur: "**Input string was not in a correct format.**"

Here is StackTrace:

```
at System.Number.StringToNumber(String str, NumberStyles options, NumberBuffer& number, NumberFormatInfo info, Boolean parseDecimal)
   at System.Number.ParseInt32(String s, NumberStyles style, NumberFormatInfo info)
   at System.String.System.IConvertible.ToInt32(IFormatProvider provider)
   at System.Convert.ToInt32(Object value, IFormatProvider provider)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JToken.op_Explicit(JToken value)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JToken.ToObject(Type objectType)
   at Breeze.Sharp.JsonEntityConverter.<>c__DisplayClassa.<ParseObject>b__6(KeyValuePair`2 kvp) in c:\GitHub\breeze.sharp\Breeze.Sharp\JsonEntityConverter.cs:line 195
   at Breeze.Sharp.Core.EnumerableFns.ForEach[T](IEnumerable`1 items, Action`1 action) in c:\GitHub\breeze.sharp\Breeze.Sharp\Core\EnumerableFns.cs:line 35
   at Breeze.Sharp.JsonEntityConverter.ParseObject(NodeContext nodeContext, EntityAspect targetAspect) in c:\GitHub\breeze.sharp\Breeze.Sharp\JsonEntityConverter.cs:line 180
   at Breeze.Sharp.JsonEntityConverter.PopulateEntity(NodeContext nodeContext, IEntity entity) in c:\GitHub\breeze.sharp\Breeze.Sharp\JsonEntityConverter.cs:line 152
   at Breeze.Sharp.JsonEntityConverter.CreateAndPopulate(NodeContext nodeContext) in c:\GitHub\breeze.sharp\Breeze.Sharp\JsonEntityConverter.cs:line 143
   at Breeze.Sharp.JsonEntityConverter.ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, Object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer) in c:\GitHub\breeze.sharp\Breeze.Sharp\JsonEntityConverter.cs:line 82
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.DeserializeConvertable(JsonConverter converter, JsonReader reader, Type objectType, Object existingValue)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.PopulateList(IList list, JsonReader reader, JsonArrayContract contract, JsonProperty containerProperty, String id)
```

When I exclude DataStore property from model, everything is working fine. It looks like that BreezeSharp is trying to parse enum as int.

I tried defining client side property as string, but that raises **InconsistentCLRPropertyDefinition** metadata mismatch. I also tried defining client side property like this:

public DataStore DataStore
{
    get
    {
        var dataStore = this.GetValue("DataStore");
        return DataStore.DEV;
    }
    set { this.SetValue(value); }
        }
But issue occurs before get is hit.

I looked at JsonEntityConverter.cs, and it looks like that enum is not handled separately at this point:

```
private void ParseObject(NodeContext nodeContext, EntityAspect targetAspect) {
      // backingStore will be null if not allowed to overwrite the entity.
      var backingStore = (targetAspect == null) ? null : targetAspect.BackingStore;
      var dict = (IDictionary<String, JToken>) nodeContext.Node;
      var structuralType = nodeContext.StructuralType;
      // needs to be the current namingConvention
      var nc = _mappingContext.EntityManager.MetadataStore.NamingConvention;
      dict.ForEach(kvp => {
        var key = nc.ServerPropertyNameToClient(kvp.Key, structuralType);
        var prop = structuralType.GetProperty(key);
        if (prop != null) {         
          if (prop.IsDataProperty) {
            if (backingStore != null) {
              var dp = (DataProperty)prop;
              if (dp.IsComplexProperty) {
                var newCo = (IComplexObject) kvp.Value.ToObject(dp.ClrType);
                var co = (IComplexObject)backingStore[key];
                var coBacking = co.ComplexAspect.BackingStore;
                newCo.ComplexAspect.BackingStore.ForEach(kvp2 => {
                  coBacking[kvp2.Key] = kvp2.Value;
                });
              } else {
                backingStore[key] = kvp.Value.ToObject(dp.ClrType);
              }
```

Does anyone has idea where to proceed from here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been fixed in Breeze 0.5.5, available now.

Comment: I confirm that enums are now supported and the issue is not present anymore. Thanks Jay!